# Using Mockito to Verify a method of from another class is called

Tags: junit, mockito

I am running into a PIT mutation problem where if it removes class.callVoidMethod() it survives. I am assuming I just need to verify that the call was made but I am having trouble getting the test case to go green. I have tried Spying and Mocking but I am getting that there were zero interaction with this mock. When debugging I am seeing that is is still calling the real method. Any idea how to get it to use the mock?

Method to test:

```
public void someMethod(String word)  
{
    word = "class"
    SomeClass class = new SomeClass();  
    class.callVoidMethod(word, "char");  
}
```

Test Case:

```
@InjectMocks
ClassUnderTest underTest;   
@Mock
SomeClass class;

@Test
public void testSomeMethod()
{
    underTest = new ClassUnderTest();
    //Not Sure if I need this
    Mockito.doCallRealMethod()
        .when(class).callSomeVoidMethod(anyString());
    underTest.someMethod("test");
    Mockito.verify(class).callSomeVoidMethod(anyString());
}
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example I got running locally. Other than some naming issues, the main problem was you weren't actually mocking `SomeClass`. Your method under test was creating and calling a real instance. Also, you do not need to create an instance of your test subject when using the runner.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class VerifyTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ClassUnderTest underTest;

    @Mock
    private SomeClass clazz;

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        underTest.someMethod("test");
        Mockito.verify(clazz).callVoidMethod("test", "char");
    }

    private static class ClassUnderTest {

        private SomeClass clazz;

        public void someMethod(String word) {
            clazz.callVoidMethod(word, "char");
        }
    }

    private static class SomeClass {
        public void callVoidMethod(String word, String otherWord) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```